# Method of using "getImageData(...)"(or similar) on an image?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have the following code to do so:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = document.getElementById("input").value;
img.onload = function(){
    console.log("loaded");
    c.height = img.height;
    c.width = img.width;
    dimensions =[img.width,img.height];
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height); 
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height).data; 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
};
```

However, on google chrome it throws the error `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

Not only that, it's a very complex way of doing a simple action. Any better ways of doing this? If not, help with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with the data? Depending on that you could possible use the FileReader.readAsDataURL(), especially since you are trying to get the data for the whole image.

Some code:

```
    var input = document.getElementById('file');
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById('uploadcanvas').getContext('2d');
    var img2 = new Image;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('uploadcanvas');
    var imgprop = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    ctx2.save();
    reader.onloadend = function(e){
        imgprop.src = e.target.result
        imgprop.onload = function(){
            ctx2.restore();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(img2.src);
            ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 100,100);
            var width = imgprop.width;
            var height = imgprop.height;
            console.log(width, height);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            img2.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
            img2.onload = function() {
                $('#display-image').css('display', "inline");
                ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
            //URL.revokeObjectURL(img2.src);
            };
            $("#button").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#button").html("Upload to Facebook");
        }

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);



function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return new Blob([ab], {
                type: 'image/png'
        });
}
```

Comment: I want to know each pixel's exact color. As in I want a RGB or a hex for each pixel, as ctx.getImageData() does.

Comment: Well in that case it definitely seems you are better of fixing the security warning rather than re inventing the wheel here. To get around the security, try loading the image, getting the binary data/blob using the filreader, putting it into a new image and make your canvas from that. I suspect the browser will not be able to tell where it is coming from then.

Comment: Thank you. I've never seen code like this. Could you link or maybe explain for learning purposes?

Comment: Here is some relevant code, you just need to take out parts and re arrange it

Comment: I don't think you need to make a blob, but I put that just in case.